# Problem resuming after suspend in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, power-management, suspend, macbook

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Macbook (white). Whenever the OS goes into Suspend after being idle for some time, it does not resume upon hitting a key or moving the mouse. I have to bring down the screen and open it again, to bring it out of suspend mode.

Furthermore, getting out of suspend mode isn't always guaranteed to use the above method. Sometimes, the screen will stay blank in spite of closing and opening the screen multiple times. If this happens, I go to `tty2` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), and do a `sudo pkill -15 Xorg`. This gets rid of the blank screen but kills all my open applications.

Any ideas/help?

Comment: Next time it happens could you add the `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` file to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use the Gnome-Shell instead of Unity?

If you don't know how to do this, execute this in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

If you want to keep with Unity, try to update your Display Driver or to install the Proprietary Drivers (like nvidia or intel graphics).